# llvm adding a 8-byte meta data for each stack allocation

Tags: c++, stack, llvm, stack-overflow

I am new to llvm pass, and I want to write a code by which I can add a metadata before each stack object allocation. In other words, whenever I see an AllocaInst, I allocated a stack and fill it with my value. However, when I am checking the stack (in gdb) I see all the metadata is added  first in the stack and then the stack objects. But I was trying to have the metadata between each stack object(as shown below)

```
<metadata>
stack_obj1
<metadata>
stack_obj2
```

This is what I wrote:

```
if (AllocaInst *AI = dyn_cast<AllocaInst>(&I)){
   IRBuilder<> IRB(AI);
   auto* A = IRB.CreateAlloca (IntTy->getPointerTo(), nullptr, "a");
   auto* V = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt8Ty(m.getContext()), <a value>)
   IRB.CreateStore(V, A, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding metadata in the following way:

```
  if (llvm::Instruction* I = dyn_cast<llvm::Instruction>(X)) {
            llvm::Value *C = llvm::ConstantInt::get(
                llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(VMContext), 100);
            llvm::MDNode *Ndata = llvm::MDNode::get(VMContext,
                llvm::ValueAsMetadata::getConstant(C));
            I->setMetadata("meta_data", Ndata);
    }
```

You will need to adapt this logic for your own code. The point to notice is that we do not need to create a store node to add some metadata to it.

Comment: Great! I can get it be the following code  
            auto *AI = dyn_cast<AllocaInst>(LI->getOperand(0));  llvm::MDNode *md = cast<llvm::MDNode>(AI->getMetadata("meta_data"));

Comment: Now I have `metadata i64 100`. I am not sure how I can pass it to a function to perform the checks? I have a c file with a function, however, since the type is metadata I can not pass it to aforementioned function. Do I necessarily need t define an intrinsic function?

Comment: I suggest that you write an IR pass. In that pass you can you this metadata in any way you want to use it.